# What's the best way to copy `previously run command` to another terminal?

Tags: command-line

There are two terminal window - terminal A and terminal B.

I typed a long long command to do something on A.

then I want to execute the same command on B.

But I would NOT like to type it again nor drag-copy-paste since it's very very long.

**What's the best(fastest) way to do so?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write out your history in the source terminal:

```
history -a
```

Then load it in your target terminal:

```
history -r
```

If you executed nothing in between, the long long command should be the third last command:

```
!-3
```

Or you can do `history`, note the number of the long long command (say 2365), and do:

```
!2365
```

---

From `help history`:

```
-a  append history lines from this session to the history file
-r  read the history file and append the contents to the history
    list
-w  write the current history to the history file
    and append them to the history list
```

You can also use `history -n` instead of `-r`:

```
-n  read all history lines not already read from the history file
```

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344455/history-a-vs-history-w-in-bash).

Comment: What does `history -a` and `history -r` do exactly?

Comment: @RNA `-a` appends the current history to the history file (usually `~/.bash_history`), and `-r` reads in the history file and appends it to the current history.